# Mejorar Wifi y LAN de Ubuntu

Tags: linux, wifi, lan

Actualmente, la velocidad máxima para la LAN de ubuntu viene de 100MB a pesar de que la tarjeta de red es de 1000 y la velocidad del servicio de internet es de 400MB alguna idea de como puedo abordar este problema.

Answer (score 1):

Segun el foro de [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1398466) usuarios que reportaron el mismo problema lo solucionaron actualizando un parámetro del GRUB con los siguientes comandos:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub 

# Buscar y editar la siguiente línea pcie_aspm=off

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash pcie_aspm=off"

sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Hice la prueba y en wifi me dio 25 MB, por ahora no mejora mucho el tema